# How can I styling the select and option tag with css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add some animation and styling for my select and option tag but having an issues when I'm using informed. Here is my `Select.js` component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { arrayOf, node, number, oneOfType, shape, string } from 'prop-types';
import {
    Option as InformedOption,
    Select as InformedSelect,
    useFieldState
} from 'informed';

import { useStyle } from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/classify';
import { FieldIcons, Message } from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/Field';
import defaultClasses from './select.module.css';
import Icon from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/Icon';
import { ChevronDown as ChevronDownIcon } from 'react-feather';

const arrow = <Icon src={ChevronDownIcon} size={24} />;

const Select = props => {
    const {
        before,
        classes: propClasses,
        field,
        items,
        message,
        ...rest
    } = props;
    const fieldState = useFieldState(field);
    const classes = useStyle(defaultClasses, propClasses);
    const inputClass = fieldState.error ? classes.input_error : classes.input;

    const options = items.map(
        ({ disabled = null, hidden = null, label, value, key = value }) => (
            <option
                key={key}
                disabled={disabled}
                hidden={hidden}
                value={value}
                style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'red' }}
            >
                {label || (value != null ? value : '')}
            </option>
        )
    );

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <FieldIcons after={arrow} before={before}>
                <InformedSelect {...rest} className={inputClass} field={field}>
                    {options}
                </InformedSelect>
            </FieldIcons>
            <Message fieldState={fieldState}>{message}</Message>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Select;

Select.propTypes = {
    before: node,
    classes: shape({
        input: string
    }),
    field: string.isRequired,
    items: arrayOf(
        shape({
            key: oneOfType([number, string]),
            label: string,
            value: oneOfType([number, string])
        })
    ),
    message: node
};
```

Anyone have idea how can I styling or change my select and option tag to ul and li and keep the same function

Added picture for select and option tag!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a limited amount of style attributes that can be applied to those elements because they're OS-dependent..

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) says about `<option>`:

> Styling the `<option>` element is highly limited. Options don't inherit the font set on the parent. In Firefox, only `color` and `background-color` can be set however in Chrome or Safari it's not possible to set any properties.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) says about `<select>`:

> The `<select>` element is notoriously difficult to style productively with CSS. You can affect certain aspects like any element — for example, manipulating the `box model`, the displayed `font`, etc., and you can use the `appearance` property to remove the default system `appearance`.
> However, these properties don't produce a consistent result across browsers, and it is hard to do things like line different types of form element up with one another in a column. The `<select>` element's internal structure is complex, and hard to control. If you want to get full control, you should consider using a library with good facilities for styling form widgets, or try rolling your own dropdown menu using non-semantic elements, JavaScript, and WAI-ARIA to provide semantics.

Comment: Can I change select option to ul and li tag with the same function ?

Comment: I wouldn't do that no. You should google on what other people do! [Here](https://medium.com/@ross.angus/styleable-select-box-replacement-in-pure-css-and-semantic-html-1f38a400b285) is an example